# Why did Neo4j change it's name to Neo5j?

Tags: neo4j

They just announced, [they changed their name to Neo5j](https://neo4j.com/blog/upgrading-product-name-exactly-what-you-think/).

I always thought that 4j meant for-Java. 
And as Neo4j is implemented in Java and Scala and the ~4j suffix has been highly popular (in the 90's) it never occurred to me that the **4j** and now **5j** is actually a version denomination.

[image]

But it seems common in database circles to use that number + letter versioning scheme, like Oracle does with **9i, 11g** and **12c**.

Now the question is what does the **5j** stand for? The article doesn't answer it. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: A related, but very important question: what does "neo" stand for? The header files reveal an interesting resolution for the abbreviation :-).

Comment: Oracle was almost through half the alphabet on their versioning, got to compete somehow. Truly an enterprise-grade update.

Comment: They just are beyond being only for Java, they are high-fiving it.

Comment: ha-ha. fooled me there for a few seconds. i thought you guys were complete fools for doing this. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Neo series of databases was developed in Sweden and attracted the 'j' suffix with the release of version 4 of the graph database. The 'j' is from the word 'jätteträd', literally "giant tree", and was used to indicate the huge data structures that could now be stored.

Incidentally the 'neo' portion of the name is a nod to a Swedish pop artist Linus Ingelsbo, who goes by the name NEO. In Neo1 the example graph was singers and bands and featured the favourite artists of the developers, including NEO. This was changed to the movie data set in the version 4 release.

Comment: Great answer thanks a lot. That explains much of the naming!

Answer (score 3):

The name neo5j is an April Fools joke - don't be fooled!

Answer (score 1):

It obviously stands so for **j**ellous, because it makes other database vendors so.